# HTML <pre> tag adds in extra line breaks

Tags: html

The HTML tag <pre> adds in a linebreak at the top and bottom of text.

So:

```
<pre>Text line     1</pre>
<pre>Text line     2</pre>
```

appears as:

```
Line     1

Line     2
```

Is there a way to only make it respect whitespaces without line breaks, in the HTML tag itself and not through CSS?

Comment: Can you combine them?

Comment: Nope you'll have to use CSS to override the user agent stylesheet which adds margin to pre tags. `pre { margin:0 };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a line break between the `pre`s, but rather, the nature of the browser's native stylesheet. Chrome, for example, sets `pre`formatted text to have margins of 1em on top and bottom.

So to remove the **margins**, you should add:

```
pre { margin: 0; }
```

There may be other browsers out there that don't impose a default 1em top/bottom margin. However, your best bet is to manually set the margins for a consistent cross browser look. Or better yet, override all the browser's native CSS styles with a CSS reset.

(for the record, Google Chrome's native stylesheet rules for `pre` tags):

```
pre, xmp, plaintext, listing {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 1em 0px; /* here's the reason you get the "line break" */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add below CSS:

```
pre{
    margin:0;
    }
```

Check the Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/A3fxF/**